# Find the exact area of the surface rotated about the x-axis

Tags: calculus, parametric

$0 \leq t \leq 1$  and $y=9t^2$ and $x=9t-3t^3$

setting up the integral:

$\int_0^1 2\pi 9t^2 \sqrt{[9(1-t^2)^2]+[9(2t)^2]}$

Factor out the 9 to give:
$\int_0^1 54 \pi t^2 \sqrt{(1-t^2)^2 + 4t^2}$ This should get simplified to 
$162 \pi \int_0^1 ((1-t^2)+2t)t^2$

should give:

$162 \pi \int_0^1 t^2-t^4+2t^3 \to \frac{1}{3}t^3-\frac{1}{5}t^5+\frac{1}{2}t^4 \vert_0^1 \to (\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{2}) \times 162 \pi$

but this this gives a negative answer...if someone could explain in detail what happens inside the square root that would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually get for the integral

$$2 \pi \int_0^1 dt \sqrt{(9-9 t^2)^2 + (18 t)^2} (9 t^2) $$

which can be simplified down to

$$162 \pi \int_0^1 dt \sqrt{(1-t^2)^2+4 t^2} (t^2) $$

which can be very simplified down to$:

$$162 \pi \int_0^1 dt \, (1+t^2) t^2  $$

which at this point I assume you can do.

Comment: How did you get $(18t)^2(9t)^2$?

Comment: @K.Gibson: the $9t^2$ term is outside the square root.

Comment: okay but factoring out a 9 gives 3(9)(2)=54 how did you get 162? I see that I needed to do a better job with keeping my powers organized but I don't see how you got 162 pi

Comment: $9 \cdot 9 \cdot 2$.

Comment: Okay I understand I pull out two 9's and get another 9 in addition to the 9 that is already on the outside

Comment: But I think you left out a $+2t$ as when $(2t)^2$ gets pulled out with $(1-t^2)^2$ I should get $((1-t^2)+2t)t^2$