# How does the following get simplified?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\sqrt{(1-t^2)^2+(2t)^2}$

I get $(1-t^2)+2t$

Someone told me it reduces to $(1-t^2)$ in a previous question here:[Find the exact area of the surface rotated about the x-axis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1908796/find-the-exact-area-of-the-surface-rotated-about-the-x-axis/1908818#1908818)

Comment: As pointed out by @tilper, while multiplication distributes over addition [e.g. $a(b+c)=ab+ac$], the square root operation does not [e.g. $\sqrt{a+b}\ne\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}$].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't say $\sqrt{a^2+b^2} = a+b$. Example: $\sqrt{9+16}$ is $5$ and not $3+4 = 7$.

Instead, you need to work from the inside out: $\sqrt{(1-t^2)^2 + (2t)^2} = \sqrt{(1 - 2t^2 + t^4) + 4t^2} = \sqrt{1 + 2t^2 + t^4}$. Can you finish it from here?

Answer (score 2):

Nooooooo.  $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ is **not** the same thing as $a + b$.  Square roots **do not** distribute over addition (or subtraction) like that.

Here's how.  I'll ignore the square root for now because we don't need it until the end.  First, expand the squares:
$$ (1-t^2)^2 + (2t)^2 = 1 - 2t^2 + t^4 + 4t^2 $$

Combine like terms:
$$ 1 - 2t^2 + t^4 + 4t^2 = 1 + 2t^2 + t^4 $$

Factor:

$$ 1 + 2t^2 + t^4 = (1 + t^2)^2 $$

Therefore, $(1-t^2)^2 + (2t)^2 = (1+t^2)^2$, and so we have
$$ \sqrt{(1-t^2)^2 + (2t)^2} = \sqrt{(1+t^2)^2} = 1 + t^2 $$